# Convert Scala's list into map with indicies as keys

Tags: list, scala, collections, dictionary

All I wanted to do is to convert the following:

`List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)` to `Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 10 )`. In other words, map index to value. It should be very easy, but I'm missing something.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to do that?

**UPD:** Just to generalizate the solution. Let say that I need to perform an additional transormation of values. For example, to wrap it with `List(_)`. In our case:

`List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)` -> `Map(0 -> List(2), 1 -> List(4), 2 -> List(6), 3 -> List(8), 4 -> List(10))`

Comment: Why not just convert it to an `IndexedSeq` (i.e., `myList.toIndexedSeq`)? It will be faster and (probably) more compact.

Comment: I need a map, since I'm planing to perfom some additional operation in feature with values/keys. But yes, in case if you need a fast random-access, `IndexedSeq` would be the best solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
val xs = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
(xs.indices zip xs).toMap
// Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 10)
```

Comment: Just curious: do you reckon that's the most efficient approach?

Comment: @ErikAllik if you mean *performance*, I think that hand written while loop will be much more efficient in tight loops, but as for the other solutions enlisted here (zipWithIndex based ones) it should show the same performance characteristics.

Answer (score 20):

```
List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
```

Comment: BTW the fact that `.zipWithIndex.toMap` didn't produce a map from the indexes to the values is a bit sad.

Comment: It’s called ‘zipWithIndex’ and not ‘zipIndexWithValues’ so the order does make *some* sense.

Comment: I prefer this to @om-nom-nom's solution as it doesn't require me to repeat the `xs` symbol. This is important to me because I'm trying to add this to the end of a long chain.

Comment: Don't forget that `zipWithIndex` trigger an extra iteration through the collection, and this can be solved by using `view`.

So, instead of:

    `List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap`

You should do:

    `List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10).view.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap`

Answer (score 5):

**UPD:** In case you want to transform the values, you can either use one of the solutions that have already been posted and then use the map's `mapValues` or you could apply the transformation beforehand:

```
List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10).zipWithIndex.map { case (v, i) => i -> List(v) }.toMap
res0: Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(0 -> List(2), 1 -> List(4), 2 -> List(6), 3 -> List(8), 4 -> L
ist(10))
```